# Taking input from a file and saving it in another file, in C, using file notation and command line statement. Unable to get output

Tags: c, file, command-line

I'm writing a program using file notation and command line statements to take input from a file, fill the input in structures, and save the input into another file. I have a sort function as well but I left it out because I think it's irrelevant to my problem. It's my first time using file notation and I can't get any output into my output file. Any ideas as to why? I've tried everything and can't get it to work. Thanks for the help.

```
/* structure declaration */
struct personCatalog {
    char name[50];
    char address[50];
    char cityState[50];
    char zipCode[7];
} ;

/* function prototypes */
void getPerson (struct personCatalog *arrayOfPointers[], int maxNumberOfPeople, FILE      *inputFile);

void sortPerson (struct personCatalog *arrayOfPointers[]);

void putPerson(struct personCatalog *arrayOfPointers[], FILE *outputFile);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int maxNumberOfPeople = 51;

    struct personCatalog *pointerArray[maxNumberOfPeople];


    /* add file streaming*/

    FILE *inFile, *outFile;

    inFile = fopen("/Users/myName/Desktop/inputText.txt", "r");

    /* add command line statements */
    if (( inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open the input file");
        exit(1);
    }

    getPerson(pointerArray, maxNumberOfPeople, inFile);

    sortPerson(pointerArray);

    outFile = fopen("/Users/myName/Desktop/outputText.txt", "w");

    if ((outFile = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open the output file");
        exit(1);
    }

    putPerson(pointerArray, outFile);

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;

}

/* function to fill the structures */
void getPerson (struct personCatalog *arrayOfPointers[], int maxNumberOfPeople, FILE *inputFile){
    struct personCatalog *tempPointer;
    int buffer = 512;
    char stringCollector[buffer];
    int num = 0;


    while ((num < maxNumberOfPeople) && (fgets(stringCollector, buffer, inputFile) != NULL) ) {

        /* dynamic memory allocation */
        tempPointer = (struct personCatalog *) malloc(sizeof(struct personCatalog));

        /* filling the structures */
        strcpy(tempPointer->name, stringCollector);
        fgets(tempPointer->address, buffer, inputFile);
        fgets(tempPointer->cityState, buffer, inputFile);
        fgets(tempPointer->zipCode, buffer, inputFile);

        arrayOfPointers[num] = tempPointer;

        num++;
    }

    /* adding a null character to the end of the pointer array */
    arrayOfPointers[num] = '\0';
}

    /* print function */
void putPerson(struct personCatalog *arrayOfPointers[], FILE *outputFile){

    int num = 0;

    while (arrayOfPointers[num] != NULL) {
        printf("------Person #%d------\n", num);
        fputs(arrayOfPointers[num]->name, outputFile);
        fputs(arrayOfPointers[num]->address, outputFile);
        fputs(arrayOfPointers[num]->cityState, outputFile);
        fputs(arrayOfPointers[num]->zipCode, outputFile);

        /* memory free */
        free(arrayOfPointers[num]);

        num++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "file notation" or what the problem is.

Comment: File notation as in 'FILE *inputFile, *outputFile. The problem is I can't get any output in the file I want. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Yeah, I've done some printf statements and still can't get output. The weirdest thing is happening. The only output I get is a printf statement I added when first writing the program. I since deleted it, saved the program, restarted my computer, and the same statement keeps showing up as my output. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you're not actually running the code you think you're running.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but is there any specific reason you're leaking whatever `FILE*`s both `inFile` and `outFile` reference and opening `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` squarely over the top of them? And what happens when `argv[2]` happens to also be `"/Users/myName/Desktop/outputText.txt"`? I'd start with cleaning up the `FILE*`s you're leaking.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks for the help Craig. I clearly didn't understand how to use command line arguments. Ha..

Answer (score 0):

Correct code in main

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int maxNumberOfPeople = 51;

struct personCatalog *pointerArray[maxNumberOfPeople];


/* add file streaming*/

FILE *inFile, *outFile;

if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Usage: /Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/progarmName-cglrwvyyabrneocwtllxqdhygaaj/Build/Products/Debug/progarmName /Users/myName/Desktop/inputText.txt /Users/myName/Desktop/outputText.txt\n");
    exit(1);
}


/* add command line statements */
if (( inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Can't open the input file");
    exit(1);
}

getPerson(pointerArray, maxNumberOfPeople, inFile);

sortPerson(pointerArray);


if ((outFile = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Can't open the output file");
    exit(1);
}

putPerson(pointerArray, outFile);

fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);

return 0;

}
```